# Using realmeter coordinates for cv2.puttext coordinates

Tags: opencv

I found the x,y coordinates that change in real time, and I want to assign this to the position value of the `cv2.puttext` function. But it keeps failing. How can I use x,y coordinates that move in real time?`

extra explain)
'it keeps failing' is when i apply in cv2.puttext

Coordinate x,y code:

```
image_hight, image_width, _ = image.shape
x_coodinate = results.pose_landmarks.landmark[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER].x * image_width
y_coodinate = results.pose_landmarks.landmark[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER].y * image_hight
```

`cv2.puttext` code:

```
cv2.putText(image, str(results.pose_landmarks.landmark[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER].x * image_width),(x_coodinate,y_coodinate),               cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Comment: What exactly is failing? What do you mean by “move in real time”? From the code you shared it is hard to see what you are actually trying.

Comment: @Markus I think the expectation is to move the text in the frame based on the `x` and `y` coordinates received from `results.pose_landmarks`

Comment: "But it keeps failing...." What is failing here? What is the current output? Are you facing errors? Is the code using `mediapipe`?, if so please mention that too.

Comment: @Markus The failure is that when I use x_cooldinate and y_cooldinate as coordinate values in the code above, the location does not change in real time. (cv2.putText(img, text, org, fontFace, fontScale, color) <- i put (x_cooldinate, y_cooldinate) in org

Comment: @JeruLuke Yes. Sir. I use mediapipe.

Comment: And what values do `x_coodinate` and `y_coodinate` return? Are they of type `float` or `int`? The more details you give, the more easy it becomes to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @JeruLuke http://colorscripter.com/s/BMbTgJF

Comment: @JeruLuke I have shared the source code to give an example. The coordinates used in cv2.puttext on line 141 make the text box move in real time. However, the cv2.puttext on line 150 that I considered is fixed at the coordinates of (a,b) and does not move. a = x_cooldinate b = y cooldinate.

Comment: @JeruLuke Oh my, it was suddenly successful. I was using anaconda, but this seems to be happening because I got the coordinates from another cell. Thank you very much. I wanted to give up, but he kept asking me questions. With my colleague, I was able to solve it without giving up until the end. thank you.